# internet explorer ignores width of div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hey guys im having a problem. Im trying to make a website with 3 columns, that looks like a flyer.

It looks fine in firefox, but in internet explorer (7 is the version on my pc), the width of the middle column width is being ignored.

Here is the code,

```
</html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="standards.css">

</head>

<body>
</div>
<div id="main">

<div id="row">

<div id ="column" style="float:left;">

</div>

<div id ="column" style="float:right;">

</div>

<div id ="column" style="margin: 0% 0% 0% 35%;">
```

```
</div>

<div id="row">

<div id ="column" style="float:left;">

</div>

<div id ="column" style="float:right;">

</div>

<div id ="column" style="margin: 0% 0% 0% 35%;">

</div>


</div>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

and the css,

```
div#column {
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;

float: top;
text-align: justify;

padding: 2em;
min-width: 16em; /* Mindestbreite (der Ueberschrift) verhindert Anzeigefehler in modernen Browsern */
height:97%;
width:25%;
background-color: #ffefd5;

}

div#row {
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;

text-align: justify;

padding: 2em;
min-width: 16em; /* Mindestbreite (der Ueberschrift) verhindert Anzeigefehler in modernen Browsern */
height:200em;
background-color: #ffefd5;

}

div#main {
float: top;
text-align: justify;

padding: 2em;
min-width: 16em; /* Mindestbreite (der Ueberschrift) verhindert Anzeigefehler in modernen Browsern */


}
```

Comment: Which code goes to the middle column? Also, have you tried the !important (just for kicks)

Comment: An `id` is supposed to be unique, you should use `class` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `div#main` is your middle column, it doesn't have a `width` set in the styles.  There is only a `min-width`.  IE7 has trouble with `min-width`.  See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width

**EDIT:**

On seeing more of the code, I think the problem is with the `width` and the `margin` on the column `div`s.  The `width` is 25% x 3 plus `margin` of 35%, which is over 100%.

Also, you have three columns all with the same `ID`.  `ID`s are for single instance use.  If you plan to use the same styles on more than one element, you need to use a `class`.  Change `#column` to `.column` in the CSS and `class="column"` in the HTML.

Comment: no i simply have a main div as container, then row divs as containers again, and then i have 3 column type divs in that.

Comment: As i understood the thing with margin, i asssume that its just 35% from the border of the parent div, since the other two divs are floating. Shouldnt there be no collision problems?

Comment: No.  See here for more on the Box Model: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113387/whats-the-relationship-between-margin-padding-and-width-in-different-browsers.  Since all three elements exist side-by-side in the row, their widths (including margins) must be 100% or less in order to prevent weirdness.